# How to create incrementing custom id that will reset every year using Laravel 8?

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a custom id like this:
YYMM-increment.

example: 2101-0001, 2101-0002

the increment will reset to 0001 each year.

How to create this id format.. Im try to use haruncpi laravel id generator but its not working

Comment: Hi Wan. It's simply done by using custom code, or I'm done some R&D here is the link.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/i-need-to-generate-a-code-with-a-auto-increment-number

Comment: Hi Kaushik. Im trying to do as your link suggestion there but failed. Is tehre any other way ? Sorry I'm new to coding world

Comment: Just get last entry from database and after increment save in your new column. Its long but you can achieve your job. For better, you can do more r&d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You.. I already found the solution. All code is setup at the controller

Note for myself in the future:-
First create a variable = find all row in table using count() function.
Then use a substr() function to get year and last increment
Do a conditioning and edit increment.
Lastly, store updated value to variable.

Answer (score 0):

if you use package laravel idgenerator , just add `'reset_on_prefix_change' => true`

```
$config = [
        'table' => 'sales',
        'field' => 'id',
        'length' => '12',
        'prefix' => 'RS-'.date('ym'),
        'reset_on_prefix_change' => true
];
```

output => RS-221100001, RS-221100002, RS-221100003

output => RS-221200001, RS-221200002, RS-221200003